# How to access binary file inside gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

How can I upload .jar or .aar file of my android module on remote location, and then can access the same file into dependencies section of gradle file of other android application.

Please update me, if there is any free public repo available for the same.

Thanks,
Sumeet

Comment: https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/

Answer (score 1):

The most popular options are [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) and [Bintray](https://bintray.com/). Check the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) for the Maven plugin for Gradle to learn how to configure your project to publish artifacts to one of the Maven repositories.

Comment: Thanks Egor, Bintray seems to be paid option, can you please confirm about Maven, as this is free or paid option?

Comment: Hi Egor, do you know about any blog or sample example on Nexus integration into android studio.